# Why not "break break"?

Tags: loops, language-design, structured-programming

Situation: You have a nested loop, and you need to break out of it.

Let's take this classic example (classic because it came from [*Goto Considered Harmful Considered Harmful*](http://web.archive.org/web/20090320002214/http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/ParaMount/papers/rubin87goto.pdf)): Given a 2-dimensional `NxN` square integer matrix `X`, find the first row with no zeroes.

I'll go through a few ways that different languages would solve this. I suppose I should start with how it *could* be written, but isn't.

```
//using "chained breaks"
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if( X[i][j] == 0 ){
            //this row isn't non-zero, so go to the next row
            break continue;
                //break out of the inner loop and continue the outer loop
        }
    }
    //if we get to here, we know this row doesn't have zeroes
    return i;
}
return -1; //failure; exact val doesn't matter for this question
```

C and its mostly-faithful derivatives:

```
//goto
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if( X[i][j] == 0 ){
            //this row isn't non-zero, so go to the next row
            goto next; //skip past the return
        }
    }
    //if we get to here, we know this row doesn't have zeroes
    return i;
    label next;
}
return -1; //failure; exact val doesn't matter for this question
```

Java:

```
//labeled loops and labeled break/continue
outer: for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if( X[i][j] == 0 ){
            //this row isn't non-zero, so go to the next row
            continue outer; //go to the next row
        }
    }
    //if we get to here, we know this row doesn't have zeroes
    return i;
}
return -1; //failure; exact val doesn't matter for this question
```

PHP:

```
//this PHP may be wrong, it's been a while
for($i=0;$i<$N;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$N;$j++){
        if( $X[$i][$j] == 0 ){
            //this row isn't non-zero, so go to the next row
            continue 2;
                //continue the outer loop
        }
    }
    //if we get to here, we know this row doesn't have zeroes
    return $i;
}
return -1; //failure; exact val doesn't matter for this question
```

Using a flag:

```
//using a flag
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    bool foundzero = false;
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        if( X[i][j] == 0 ){
            //this row isn't non-zero, so go to the next row
            foundzero = true;
            break; //go to the next row
        }
    }
    //if we get to here, we know this row doesn't have zeroes
    if(!foundzero)
        return i;
}
return -1; //failure; exact val doesn't matter for this question
```

Exporting the inner loop to a function:

```
//using a function call
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    if(haszero(X[i],N))
        return i;
}
return -1; //failure; exact val doesn't matter for this question

//and the haszero function
bool haszero(int arr[], int N){
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if( arr[i] == 0 ){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, all of these work, but some with function call overhead (bad if the language wants to allow for deep loops), flags (distasteful or unintuitive for some), `goto` (more powerful than you might need),or weird syntax (Java's silliness).

So why don't languages have `break break`, `break continue`, `break break continue`, etc.? (`continue break` makes little sense to no sense, as it means to go to the next iteration and then leave it). Are there problems with adding this sort of thing to the language?

Comment: Probably because of the extremely small number of registers that computers have; historically it would have been difficult to keep enough registers available to support your suggestion.

Comment: If a language supports `break break`, then it should probably support N nested loops (`break break break`, `break break break break`, etc).

Comment: I can't see a reason why this doesn't already exist, it would be easy to implement something very similar as a desugarizer or during preprocessing. And it would add even better abstraction for further features...

Comment: I may very well try and have this incorporated into the GCC... Thank you for the idea

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Registers have nothing to do with it. It all happens at compile time. The only instructions that need to be emitted are, possibly, a stack pop, and a jump. However the only possible answer to the question is "because they didn't".

Comment: Goto by any other name is still a goto... Using break and continue without labels and return before the last statement of a function enable most use cases for which purely structural syntax would be needlessly complex without falling off the edge of the structured programming world into the dreaded spaghetti bowl of goto Hell!

Comment: A single statement to perform a controlled exit out of multiple levels of loop blocks would be intrinsically difficult to maintain if one of the (perhaps distant) outer loop structures is changed later on.  In other words, as Ned implied, it's really no better than a goto statement.  Explicit named flags, while seemingly less graceful, are easier to track than block structure.

Comment: But "Are there problems with adding this sort of thing to [a] language?"

Comment: @leewangzhong No, but it's a poor idea. The labelled 'break' is a much better alternative, as it doesn't rely on the current nesting level, and therefore doesn't have to be changed if the nesting level changes.

Comment: I disagree with the "opinion" complaint. I'm asking for concerns with adding such a thing to a language, not whether it's better or worse than the alternatives.

Comment: I guess that PHP implementation is the most reasonable and sensible way.

Comment: @leewangzhong 'Opinion-based' refers to the question expressed in your title. If that doesn't reflect your actual question, whose fault is that?

Comment: "Why not"? "What reasons are there for this not to be the case?" Not "Should this be the case?"